# Insert "where" rule in a "foreach" search

Tags: asp.net-mvc, foreach

I need some help in order to put a where rule into the foreach search. My goal is to exclude orders where the customerOrder.ERPOrderNumber starts with letter E

The code that i have returns all the orders for the specific customer.

Thank you in advance for your help.

```
 @foreach (var customerOrder in Model.CustomerOrders)
        { 
            <tr>
                <td class="mavo-order-date">@customerOrder.OrderDate.ToShortDateString()
                </td>
                <td class="mavo-status">@customerOrder.Status
                </td>
                <td class="mavo-order-number">
                    <a href="@Url.Action("OrderHistoryDetail", "Account", new { orderId = customerOrder.ERPOrderNumber })">@customerOrder.OrderNumber</a>
                </td>
                @if (Model.ShowErpOrderNumber)
                {
                    <td class="mavo-erp-order">@customerOrder.ERPOrderNumber
                    </td>
                }
                <td class="mavo-po">@customerOrder.CustomerPO
                </td>
                <td class="mavo-order-total">@customerOrder.OrderGrandTotal.ToCurrency()
                </td>
                <td class="mavo-view">
                    <a class="btn btnStyleA tbm5" href="@Url.Action("OrderHistoryDetail", "Account", new { orderId = customerOrder.ERPOrderNumber })">View Details</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put an `if` statement inside the `foreach` loop to only write out the table row when the order number doesn't start with the letter `E`.

```
@foreach (var customerOrder in Model.CustomerOrders)
{  
    @if(!customerOrder.ERPOrderNumber.StartsWith("E")) 
    {
       // Markup goes in here
    }
}
```

Or you can use LINQ to filter the `CustomerOrders` collection.

```
@foreach(var customerOrder in Model.CustomerOrders.Where(x => !x.StartsWith("E"))
```

Comment: The first suggestion worked fine but I had to take the @ from the if statement out.

Thank you for your help,

Bobby

Comment: @CharalamposAfionis, No problem, and you're right. I forgot that the code block would still be active from the `foreach` statement. If this solved your problem, please don't forget to click the checkmark to mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks.